# search for the same number in the beginning and the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write `regexp` to find a string who start and ends with the same number like so :

```
2aldkc2 <---- 
4alou4 <----
```

edit , i forget to motion what i have tried so far :

```
^(\d).^([^h].*$)
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: What do you expect from your examples? What have you tried? Why does it not work? We won't do the work for your. We help with questions.

Comment: this is not doing the work for me this is a simple regexp i was asking for help and not doing my work !!

Comment: You did not show any effort in solving it yourself => we do your work.

Comment: show some effort (maybe after edition) and if he was a master of regex, he does not ask such a question, so it's OK. @usr1234567 several of you post are in the same way (even if longer in text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use capturing group.

```
^(\d).*\1$
```

The regex captures the first digit and match that particular line only if the last character is also the same as the one captured.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rR5zI0/4)